# Multithread; HibernateException, Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, repository

I understand somewhat the exception, but not how to solve it. Most of my concurrent threads will target the same object graph with a SaveOrUpdate. Can I then have only a single session open at any time? If so, how can I enforce that over multiple threads?

```
public class FnhManagerTS
{
    private static Configuration cfg;
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static string connectionString;
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static ISession _session = null; 

    private FnhManagerTS() { }

    private static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        // Create a database connection and open a ISession on it.
        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ThreadStatic ISession.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ISession Session()
    {
        if (_session != null && _session.IsOpen)
            return _session;
        else
        {
            _session = OpenSession();
            return _session; 
        }
    }
```

Repo:

```
public class GenericRepoTS<T>
    where T : class
{
    private ISession session;

    public GenericRepoTS()
    {
        this.session = FnhManagerTS.Session();
    } 

    public void SaveOrUpdate(IList<T> instances)
    {
        if (instances != null)
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                { 
                    lock (instances)
                    {
                        foreach (var i in instances)
                        {
                            session.SaveOrUpdate(i);
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback(); 
                    Trace.TraceError("GenericRepository.SaveOrUpdate IList<" + typeof(T).ToString() + "> ", ex.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate sessions are not thread safe and by logical corollary, neither are database connections generally. You need one session (connection) per thread.

Comment: Isn't that what I have, when I declare [ThreadStatic] ISession?

Comment: I would avoid [ThreadStatic], instead use CallContext if in a non-ASP.NET runtime scenario or HttpContext.Current.Items if in an ASP.NET runtime scenario. NEVER use CallContext or [ThreadStatic] in ASP.NET. See the following link for an example in my open source project TextMetal:

http://code.google.com/p/textmetal/source/browse/src/TextMetal.Core/Plumbing/ExecutionPathStorage.cs

You can change up code to make it work with NHibernate as I have in the past and know it works. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I'm only dealing with winforms. I don't really see if this is relevant, and if so what purpose it would have for my implementation of session factory / repository?

Comment: OK, lets for a moment assume your multithreaded code is correct. If that is the case, then you may be a victim of crosss session leak. Basically, when you pass in your collection, did you pull it from NHibernate previously? If so, it may be linked to another ISession...or when you do the SaveOrUpdate and return without Evict(), downstream code may touch an entity causing a SELECT against a stale ISession. At what point does the exception get thrown?

Comment: Yes the collection is pulled once from NHibernate at startup. Then subsequently I manipulate this object graph, and persist with SaveOrUpdate, from multiple concurrent threads. I understand to some degree why this may cause exceptions, but my problem is I struggle to understand how people solve this. Like; Is it at all possible to have one thread update an object graph that another thread is in the process of persisting by SaveOrUpdate, without throwing an exception?

Comment: Evict() takes an object (and it's collections) out of the session so that it isn't written to the database when Flush() is called. You can re-attach the object using Update().

Comment: So you say I should always Evict any object after commit in a SaveOrUpdate, to always work with detached entities..? Is this a normal practice for multithread applications?

Comment: Anytime you want to work with cross session entities, you will have to do Evict() to prevent using a stale session or session from a stale thread. Same thing goes for web apps as they are inherently multithreaded...except they are usually one-session-per-request-and-dispose usage scenario but I digress.

Comment: I ran into the same problems. I'm using a one-session-per-request scenario, but this still occurs sometimes (not always). I am using a HttpSession to store the Entity, can this trigger the problem?

Comment: Are you evicting the entity before putting into session?